# SystemVerilog: Creating packed arrays using variables

Tags: arrays, task, system-verilog

I would like to create a task that does the following in SystemVerilog:

1. Receive the 3 input parameters and 1 output parameter.
2. Randomizes a data and assign the data to a bit variable (output parameter).

   ```
   1. task rand_wr_data(input int size, int data_range_hi, int data_range_lo, output bit [31:0] data);
   2.     bit unsigned [(size - 1):0] rand_data_bits;
   3.     bit unsigned [(data_range_hi - data_range_lo):0] wr_data_bits;
   4.    
   5.     int unsigned rand_data = $urandom();
   6.     wr_data_bits = rand_data;
   7.     data = wr_data_bits << (data_range_lo + 1);
   8. endtask: rand_data
   ```

The above code will give me an error as of **Non-constant expression error on line 2 and 3** whereby I've to use a constant in declaring the range for an array. I've tried the following but to no avail.

```
    [parameter | localparam | const] int data_size = size;
```

Therefore, I've a few enquiries as follows:

1. Is there a way to create a packed array using variables like in my code?
2. Is there another way to do what I would like to do above?
3. Can I receive variable size array as a task parameter instead of an array that has to have its size declared?
4. In line 6 of my code, I would like to assign an unsigned int to a 32-bit array but I receive different result after that. How can I accomplish that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring to the error: **Non-constant expression**. The **size** of all the **packed variables** must be defined at **compile-time**. But here you are providing a *run-time* size which is not *feasible*. Henceforth the error.

There can be a few useful and not-so-useful workarounds as follows:

Declare `size`, `data_range_hi` and `data_range_lo` as parameters. Since **parameters** are **evaluated** during **compile/elaboration time**, this shall work. But you cannot change those parameters directly at run-time.

```
task rand_wr_data ( output bit [31:0] data);
  parameter int size=8, data_range_hi=8,data_range_lo=0;
  bit unsigned [(size - 1):0] rand_data_bits;
```

As an alternative and an **effective way**, referring to [SystemVerilog LRM 1800-2012](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/02/25/ieee-1800-2012-systemverilog-published/)section 13.8:

> A **parameterized subroutine** allows the user to generically specify or define an implementation. When using that subroutine one may provide the parameters that fully define its behavior. This allows for only **one definition** to be **written** and **maintained** instead of **multiple subroutines** with different array sizes, data types, and variable widths.

And the following paragraph:

> The way to implement parameterized subroutines is through the use of **static methods** in **parameterized classes** (see 8.10 and 8.25).
>
> The class may be declared **virtual** in order to **prevent object construction** and enforce the strict **static** usage of the **method**.

You can create a parameterized `virtual` class and `static` task inside it. Call to this task is to be made using the **scope resolution operator** (`::`) and parameter overriding. Something can be done as follows:

```
virtual class wrapper #(parameter int size=8, int data_range_hi=8, int data_range_lo=0);
 static task rand_wr_data(output bit [31:0] data);
 bit unsigned [(size - 1):0] rand_data_bits;
 // ...
 // ...
 endtask
endclass
// ...
// in some module/class, call task
wrapper #(16,8,0)::rand_wr_data (a);
// ...
```

Declaring class as `virtual` makes sure that no objects can be created for that class. The example given in LRM section 13.8 might also be useful.

A working example is made at [EDAPlayground here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/E7s).

**Coming to your questions**:

> Is there a way to create a packed array using variables like in my code?

Yes, as discussed above.

> Is there another way to do what I would like to do above?

There might be other ways like `define` directives which can be set at run-time by user, but they'll remain constant in entire simulation.

> Can I receive variable size array as a task parameter instead of an array that has to have its size declared?

Yes, as discussed above.

> In line 6 of my code, I would like to assign an unsigned int to a 32-bit array but I receive different result after that. How can I accomplish that?

Bit is by-default `unsigned`, so no need to declare `bit unsigned`, just `bit` shall work; but that's not the problem. The problem here seems `wr_data_bits` is defined as `bit unsigned [(data_range_hi - data_range_lo):0] wr_data_bits;` while `rand_data` is defined as `int unsigned rand_data`. The **size** of both may **vary**.

In case you pass `31` as `(data_range_hi - data_range_lo)`, the values will match. The given sample code link shows equal values.

```
wr_data_bits = 5e23536 rand_data = 5e23536
```

I've tried googling it but didn't find much information. For more information refer [this](http://www.eda.org/sv-bc/hm/10570.html) link.